# Opposite of underscore ._without(array, value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Looking at the [underscore array methods](http://underscorejs.org/#arrays), I dont see what I want to accomplish.

This removes `0` and `1` from the array:

```
_.without([1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4], 0, 1);
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

What if I need only `0` and `1`?

```
=> [1, 1, 0 ,1]
```

Underscorde would make me write less javascript code.

**Clarity:**

Example if `0, 1` is in the array, leave all values of `1`'s and `0`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I found:

```
var allArray = [1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4];
var leaveOnly = [1, 0];

var result = _.filter(allArray, _.partial(_.contains, leaveOnly)); // [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

[`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains), [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eeLcrmvt/

If you are going to use this quite often, you can create a mixin:

```
_.mixin({
  filterOut: function(arr, leave) {
    return _.filter(arr, _.partial(_.contains, leave))
  }
});

var result = _.filterOut([ 1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ]);

console.log(result); // [ 1, 0, 1, 1 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a web link for those methods you have used?

Comment: Yes I will. Marvelous!

Answer (score 0):

The `underscore` way

```
var zerosones = _.filter([1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4], function(num){ 
    return (num === 0 || num === 1); 
});
=> [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

using [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) method

Without `underscore` ( `es5` ) you can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a pretty good [compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)

```
var completeArray = [1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4];
completeArray =  completeArray.filter(function(value){ 
   return (value === 1 || value === 0) 
});

console.log(completeArray); //[1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: What if I want every number lower than 8? Thats redundant.
`var array = [ 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4 ].filter(function(value) { return [ 0, 1 ].indexOf(value) >= 0; });`

Comment: Not me, but why would you answer a question that's quite clearly asking for an **Underscore** way of doing it with a non-Underscore way of doing it? **Unless**, of course, you can say (for certain) "Underscore doesn't have that feature, but you can do it without Underscore." (And you may well be able to say that, but I don't know Underscore enough to be sure. `intersection` isn't quite right, for instance...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if theres is a way to avoid using an external library in favor of plain JS why don't use it?

Comment: @AreWojciechowski the OP is asking for 0's and 1's what does that mean?

Comment: @steo but what if he suddenly changes his mind, or someone else will find this question? Your approach in this answer is simply not cool.

Comment: There's *always* a way to make your own methods, but that's rarely a good reason by itself.

Comment: @Juhana but it is a plain javascript method, really flexible by the way.

Comment: @AreWojciechowski your point has no reason, your practically saying that every answer should be generic, while this question is really specific

Comment: Hi all. The question is straight forward. I need the opposite of `_.without` So example if `0, 1` is in the array, leave all values of `1` and `0`.

Comment: @Sylar what does that mean?

Comment: @AreWojciechowski: I'm with steo, the question specifically asks for 0 and 1, so an answer using 0 and 1 is entirely appropriate. If someone needs different values, they'll use different values, it's perfectly obvious where they go.

Comment: @steo: I don't think there's an Underscore method more specific than [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter). I suggest updating your answer to show how to use `_.filter` for this, and then *also* saying that as of ES5 and higher, you could just use `Array#filter` to do the same thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fixed the answer. I basically thought it was useless to use underscore but didn't think about that it was only a ES5+ feature.

Comment: :-) We're nearly in an ES5+ world anyway, and it can be shimmed. I always thought the downvotes were inappropriate, and when it was clear Underscore didn't offer anything better than `Array#filter`...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest `underscore` way I found is this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4];
console.log(_.difference(arr, _.without(arr, 1, 0)));
```

or if you have your args in an array:

```
console.log(_.difference(arr, _.difference(arr, [1, 0])));
```